# Amazon Fire-Os can't handle stream intent

Tags: kindle-fire, amazon-fire-tv

Is it possible to open a stream on Fire-TV using an Intent like you normally do in android?
This code will show no players that can handle the intent:

```
playerIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
playerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
playerIntent.setDataAndType("http://localhost/videostream", "video/*");
startActivity(playerIntent);
```

This wont work either:

```
//      playerIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.amazon.avod", "com.amazon.avod.playbackclient.EdPlaybackActivity"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireTV doesn't have a stand-alone video player. Your options would be to either add a MediaElement to your app to display the content or use a WebView with a  element in (though it looks like they recommend the VisualOn SDK for higher quality video where hardware acceleration will make it look better). Not sure if there are any 3rd party video players in the store that would listen to the event if you just want to hand-off playback.

Depending on the app, have you looked at the HTML5 based [Web App Starter Kit](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx1A9SK34ET4SL6/Introducing-the-Web-App-Starter-Kit-for-Fire-TV) that's just been added?